# How to get updating error from Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have Spring Data Repisotory which contains a method for updating, and other lays of that chain:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = ADMIN_RESTAURANTS_URL, produces = JSON_TYPE)
public class AdminRestaurantController implements Controller {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantService restaurantService;

    @PutMapping("/{restaurantId}")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void update(@PathVariable Integer restaurantId,
                       @Valid @RequestBody Restaurant restaurant,
                       @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        log.info("update restaurant with id {} of user {}", restaurantId, user.getId());
        restaurantService.update(restaurantId, restaurant, user);
    }
}

@Service
public class RestaurantService {

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;

    public void update(Integer restaurantId, Restaurant restaurant, User user) {
        restaurantRepository.setRestaurantByIdAndUserId(restaurant.getName(), restaurant.getAddress(), restaurantId, user.getId());
    }
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Repository
public interface RestaurantRepository extends CrudRepository<Restaurant, Integer>, JpaRepository<Restaurant, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update Restaurant r set r.name = ?1, r.address = ?2 where r.id = ?3 and r.user.id = ?4")
    void setRestaurantByIdAndUserId(String name, String address, Integer id, Integer userId);
}
```

I have the first user with id = 1, and he has a restaurant with id = 11.
I also have the second user with id = 2 and his restaurant with id = 12.

I need to handle an exception, when I'm trying to update restaurant with id = 12 by user with id = 1 (because he is not an owner of that restaurant, he owns only the restaurant with id = 11).

Now, when I do this update - it won't be done, and my database doesn't return me any status or error.
But I want to handle some Exception with a message like "Requested restaurant not found"(it can be my custom). How I can get it?

UPD. There is my script for creating tables:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence START WITH 100000;

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id         INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('hibernate_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
    name       VARCHAR(255)         NOT NULL,
    password   VARCHAR(255)         NOT NULL,
    is_enabled BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_unique_name_idx ON users (name);
CREATE INDEX user__idx ON users (id);

CREATE TABLE restaurants
(
    id      INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('hibernate_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    name    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX restaurants_unique_name_address_idx ON restaurants (name, address);
CREATE INDEX restaurants_id_idx ON restaurants (id, user_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manually write JPQL/SQL to update records as it is difficult to implement rich business logic. Implement your update logic in your service. First use repository to get the record that that you want to update as a java object, then validate if the update is allowed using java codes , and directly update the state of this object if it is allowed . Hibernate will generate the update SQL automatically and you don't need to write the JPQL/SQL manually.

Something looks like :

```java
@Service
public class RestaurantService {

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void update(Integer restaurantId, Restaurant restaurant, User user) {
        Restaurant restaurantToUpdate = restaurantRepository.findById(restaurantId).orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException("No restaurant with this ID is found"));

        if(!restaurantToUpdate.getOwnerId().equals(user.getId())){
            throw new RuntimeException("Permission denined as the restaurant the user is not the owner. ")
        }

        //Do your update here such as ......
        restaurantToUpdate.setAddress(restaurant.getAddress());
        .........
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this variant, but I just wanted not to do one more request to database. Now I understand it's a mistake. Thank you so much!